# Need to override edit.phtml on cart page to add new button near it

Tags: magento2, overrides

I need to add new button near edit button on cart page. I want o override `edit.phtml` in my **custom module**. 
 Can someone guide me how to achieve this?

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to override the template then you can use plugin**

*Create after Plugin  getTemplate  method  on the  class*  `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit`

and use your *template file as the alternative of `default.phtml`*

**Create `di.xml`  at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/` for define the plugin class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit">
      <plugin name="change_template_for_edit" type="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Cart\EditPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**And finally, add the plugin class `EditPlugin.php` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Cart`**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Cart;
class EditPlugin
{

       public function afterGetTemplate(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit $subject,
     $result
) { // use Own module edit.phtml
    return '{Vendorname}_{Modulename}::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml';
}

}
```

Create a template file which is replicate of default `edit.phtml` at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}//view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml`

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /Plugin/Cart/EditPlugin.php on line 7

Comment: Fixed, the syntax issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Copy the file in

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml

2. Go to 
   app/design/frontend/Your_Namespace/Your_Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions
3. Paste the copied file edit.phtml into your theme

Comment: This is working fine but if i want it to be done via app/code/cutom module then how can these be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Copy edit.phtml from core file

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\renderer\actions
```

Keep edit.phtml file in below path

```
app\design\frontend\Your_Vendor\Your_Theme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\renderer\actions
```

Do your changes and clear the cache and check.

Comment: This is working fine but if i want it to be done via app/code/cutom module then how can these be achieved.

Comment: I think, you dont need to create a custom module for this file it is just a default magento file so you can override in the theme as i suggested.

Comment: You are right @Rakesh, we can do as you suggested, but i am suggesting to Arjun that there is no need to create custom module because this is just a simple file

Answer (score 0):

You need to override in your module like below.

**First copy an edit.phtml file in your module like**

> app/code/Mycompany/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml

Add Button code in this file.

After that create a file

> app/code/Mycompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

And add the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override" as="renderer.list.custom"/>
    <arguments>
        <argument name="renderer_list_name" xsi:type="string">checkout.cart.item.renderers.override</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Then create this file

> app/code/Mycompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

And add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" as="actions">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Mycompany_MyModule::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" as="actions">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Mycompany_MyModule::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

**Note: Please check Mycompany_MyModule in above file to override edit.phtml file.**

Clear cache and check, Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I have tried the code but doesn't work as expected.